# Installing PyQt5 on OS X crashes pip

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt5

Trying to install PyQt5 on my work laptop. When I try to `pip3 search PyQt` I get

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 43, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py", line 60, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1098, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1437, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 767, in request
    return self.parse_response(response.raw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1327, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/xmlrpc/client.py", line 657, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: :'_pypi_hidden'">
```

and if I try `pip3 install PyQt5` I get

```
Collecting PyQt5
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt5
```

The PyQt docs clearly state that this should work. Am I doing something wrong? Is my pip broken? What is going on?

Comment: Where is written that you can install PyQt5 using pip? Normally you can't afaik they don't distribute setups under PyPi, because it's difficult to provide the correct Qt binaries.

Comment: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html

Comment: besides, even if it is not provided, why does it crash pip to search for it?

Comment: If you want a prepackaged pyqt on OS X, you need to have macports installed and then `port install pyqt5`.

Comment: I don't use macports, I use homebrew. There is a homebrew package for PyQt5, but it is built against a different version of python from the one I am using. Anyway, I built PyQT5 from source already, going to leave the question here because this is definitely not a documented behavior for either pip or PyQt5